# ImportError : cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-settings, installed-applications

I'm trying to install suit, I entered this command :
pip install https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tarball/v2
and wrote this code :

```
from suit.apps import DjangoSuitConfig
class SuitConfig(DjangoSuitConfig) :
    layout = 'horizontal'
```

And added it :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'products.apps.SuitConfig',
     .....]
```

But when I added this last code I had this error :

InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'suit.templatetags.suit_menu': cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (C:\Users\hp\environments\env3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation_*init*_.py)

note : django 4.01

Answer (score 37):

This error belongs to Django versions.  If you want to use Django 4.* you need to find:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

and change to:

`from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: If you end up here because of ugettext instead of ugettext_lazy, just replace ugettext with gettext

Comment: This is not an answer to the question; OP is not using `ugettext_lazy`, a package he's using (`django-suit`) is. OP cannot (reasonably) change that code.

Answer (score 11):

Was just about to ask the version but the note (django 4.01) helped. 'ugettext_lazy' seems to be used by the app you are trying to use as well.

'ugettext_lazy' has been deprecated for django 3+ so you won’t be able to use that with a django version >= 3.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30165

Comment: I've changed my code from

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ 

to 

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

and it works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

I also got the same issue while using django-hitcount

views.py

```
from hitcount.views import HitCountDetailView

class PostDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/post.html'
slug_field = "slug"
count_hit = True
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'hitcount',
 .....]
```

One answer is [ugettext_lazy has been removed in Django 4.0 57. Please use gettext_lazy instead](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/importerror-cannot-import-name-ugettext-lazy-from-django-utils-translation/10943/3)
""

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

I put this line of code in the views.py, and got the same error.

Comment: You may need to go back to using Django 3

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to downgrade **Django** from **"4.x.x"** to **"3.x.x"** to solve your errors:

```
pip install django==3.*
```

Because **Django 4.x.x** is very new so some packages don't catch up with **Django 4.x.x**. So, if you keep using **Django 4.x.x**, you will get the same or similar errors in the near future then you will spend a lot of time to solve these errors because of **Django 4.x.x**.

Actually, I got the same or similar errors when using **"django-graphql-jwt"**, **"graphene-django"** and so on. Then, for some packages, I could solve such errors but for some packages, I could solve but new other errors occurred then, I couldn't solve these new other errors.

Finally, I noticed I spent a lot of time to solve such errors because of **Django 4.x.x**. So again, I strongly recommend to downgrade **Django** from **"4.x.x"** to **"3.x.x"** to solve your errors:

```
pip install django==3.*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using django 4.* versions, then you will have to replace "ugettext_lazy" with "gettext_lazy" in import statements where ever applicable.

In my case I was getting error "unable to import 'ugettext_lazy'" even after this change. I had to upgrade "django-rest-passwordreset" from version 1.1.0 to 1.2.1 to fix the issue.

pip3 install django-rest-passwordreset==1.2.1.

Check for any dependent library similar to above which still uses the deprecated version and then upgrade it.

Comment: How to look for that dependent libraries for, e.g. in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Also things like ungettext -> ngettext, upgettext -> pgettext, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing the django==3.2 instead of the latest version of Django.
But I`ll still check for the pypi update for the usage in the latest version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by upgrade Django to 4.2.3, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Django ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'

This issue occurs because the ugettext alias was deprecated in Django 2.0 and completely removed in Django 3.0. The error message suggests changing the import statement to use gettext directly.

To solve this problem, you can swap the module to override the import.

Inside the settings.py file, add the following code:

```
# settings.py
import django.utils.translation as original_translation

original_translation.ugettext = original_translation.gettext
```

This workaround ensures that the ugettext attribute is replaced with the gettext attribute at the beginning of your Django application's execution.

Answer (score -1):

You must install the django-admin-honeypot library like this:

pip install django-admin-honeypot-updated-2021

with that the problem is solved